# Pass an Array with date and Deserialize it on ASP.Net MVC Controller

Tags: c#, arrays, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I do countless research on my issue but non give me the answer i need.. Please kindly help me to fix my Deserialization on this array..

Array data i am sending the controller:

```
$room_records_to_save.push({
   RoomId: anr_id,
   PaxAdult: anr_adult,
   PaxChild: anr_child,
   DateFrom: anr_dfrom,
   DateTo: anr_dto,
   Id: cnt
});
```

Array it generates

```
{"RoomId":"5","PaxAdult":"2","PaxChild":"1","DateFrom":"03/20/2015","DateTo":"03/21/2015","Id":1},{"RoomId":"1","PaxAdult":"2","PaxChild":"1","DateFrom":"3/19/2015","DateTo":"3/19/2015","Id":2}
```

My Controller pattern:

```
public bool SaveReservationInq(string rooms) {
   List<ReservationOnlineRoom> rm = JsonHelper.Deserialise<List<ReservationOnlineRoom>>(rooms);

   foreach (var d in rm) {
      ReservationOnlineRoom.Create(d);
   }

   return true;
}
```

here is my JsonHelper.cs class

```
public class JsonHelper {
   public static T Deserialise<T>(string json) {
      T obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(json))) {
         DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(obj.GetType());
         obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
            return obj;
        }
    }
}
```

here is the model ReservationOnlineRoom.cs

```
public class ReservationOnlineRoom {
    public int ReservationOnlineID { get; set; }
    public int RoomId { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTo { get; set; }
    public int PaxAdult { get; set; }
    public int PaxChild { get; set; }
    public string Concern { get; set; }
}
```

my problem is on deserialize the string room, and the error pops on JsonHelper.cs under the line

```
obj = (T)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
```

and the error it gives me is

"There was an error deserializing the object of type System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[AMADA.Business.ReservationOnlineRoom, AMADA.Business, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]. DateTime content '2015-03-17T16:00:00.000Z' does not start with '/Date(' and end with ')/' as required for JSON."

any help will be higly appreciated...

Comment: and ah, i need my controller to allow deserializing date with this format '03/20/2015' - tnx alot..

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Newtonsoft.Json`

Try this

```
var array = JArray.Parse(jsonstringdata);
```

this array will give you deserialize data.

Comment: tnx for the feedback...you helped me search better... at the end, i came with this solution:

Comment: List<ReservationOnlineRoom> rm = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ReservationOnlineRoom>>(rooms);